How to test for statistical significance on a multi-country dataset?
I am attempting to test for statistical significance between treatment and control groups, with data from 7 countries, using a Welch 2-sample t-test [t.test() in R]. 6 out of 7 countries have statistically significant results but when I aggregate the dataset to test for significance at a multi-country level, I am getting a high p-value. Is there a better approach to accurately measure the effect of the treatment when the data has been aggregated into a multi-country dataset?
I am wondering if the reason I find low p-values for each country (in 6 out of 7), yet a high p-value when aggregated is because the starting and ending points are quite different between countries. Attached is a box plot that illustrates what I am trying to describe.
Is there a methodology to "calibrate" values before testing for multi-country statistical significance?


This depends a lot on the question you're trying to answer and the background knowledge on the problem.  Generally, a linear regression might be useful here, but if you think that the effect will depend on the country then that might change the approach a little.  It looks like your data are bounded below by 0, so a different model may be needed (one that respects the boundary).  But before we start talking about models, can you tell us what you're measuring here and what the "treatment" was?
